# What to do when a questioner edits the answer into the question?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should an appended answer *within* a question be moved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103154/should-an-appended-answer-within-a-question-be-moved)

How should we deal with a poster who edits an answer into a question?

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663133/full-list-of-all-subscripts-and-diacritical-marks-in-unicode) (not to pick on that particular user); I've seen others.  In case the question is edited before you read this, I've quoted it below.

IMHO this is not a huge deal, but it's a bit inappropriate.  Questions should be questions, and answers should be answers -- and since the distinction is clear in the vast majority of posts, editing the answer into the question is potentially confusing.  The way to indicate that a question has been answered is to accept an answer, even if you've posted it yourself.  The site's user interface is designed around this idea.

My question is, how should we deal with cases like this?  The questioner obviously had good intentions, and I don't particularly want to downvote or flag it.  Sometimes I post a comment suggesting that answers should be answers; is that the best response?

Here's the question in question:

> Answered: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt is a a
>   list of all unicode chars, and 0xcc99 # U+0319 COMBINING RIGHT TACK
>   BELOW is somewhat like a comma for a monospaced font..(example:
>   10̡9̡8̡7̡6̡5̡4̡3̡2̡1̡0̡ )
>
> Is there a complete list of all unicode characters along with their
>   verbal descriptions, e.g. a list of lines like ... 0xcc99 # U+0319
>   COMBINING RIGHT TACK BELOW ..
>
> Particularly, what diacritical mark do I use to type 1. or 2o3 ? The
>   motivation is that I want to be able to add a point or comma in a
>   monospace font in a terminal, without actually adding a character.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a big deal since the poster did accept the answer, if not it might be more questionable. I definitely see this as a lesser problem than posters that do not accept answers at all.

Comment: Even though it may not be a big deal, it should at least be edited so the answer is at the **bottom** so that the short description is still the question and not the answer.